# how record a query firebase database in List with flutter?

Tags: list, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, flutter

First, sorry for my english because it is very bad.

In my realtime database in firebase I have :

```
 -  consommables
   + produit1 : 0
   + produit2 : 0
   + produit3 : 0
   + ........ : 0




 - nameUser
   - consommables
     + produit1 : 1
     + produit2 : 0
     + produit3 : 0
     + ........ : 1
```

I would like to compare all sub-categories of "consommables" with all sub-categories of "name/consommables", and if there are some sub-categories in "consommables" which do not exist in the sub-category "name/consommables", I want to store the value 0 for those records.

For this, I want make 2 queries in List and I want compare the 2 Lists. But I don't know how to record a query in List.

Can you help me please ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To capture the results of a query in a list, observe the `onChildAdded` and the `onValue` streams. The `onChildAdded` will give you the nodes matching the query in the right order, while the `onValue` tells you when the results are done.

For an example of this, see the [`FirebaseList` class](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/blob/6b6c6404715297c8324b57ece5ecf638431bbd9e/packages/firebase_database/lib/ui/firebase_list.dart#L96) in the FlutterFire library. You can also consider using a [`FirebaseList` object](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_database/latest/ui_firebase_list/ui_firebase_list-library.html) as the bases for your own problem. Just pass your query into the `FirebaseList` constructor to get started, and then you can access the nodes through the [`[]` operator](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/blob/6b6c6404715297c8324b57ece5ecf638431bbd9e/packages/firebase_database/lib/ui/firebase_list.dart#L72).